# I need a regex expression to separate each word and <br>

Tags: regex

What I need is super straight forward however I simply cannot figure it out.  I am using regex101.com to try and nail down the correct regex but nothing seems to work.

Basically what I need is to create a list of words and `<br>` tags in an array.

It could be any of these `<br>` tags, `<br>, <br/>, <br >, <br />`

So for `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br /><br />Duis eu metus porttitor, maximus elit vitae, sodales leo.`

I need an expression that will give me

```
["Lorem ", "ipsum ", "dolor ", "sit ", "amet, ", "consectetur ", "adipiscing ", "elit.", "<br />", "<br />", "Duis ", "eu ", "metus ", "porttitor, ", "maximus ", "elit ", "vitae, ", "sodales ", "leo. "]
```

So far all I have is `/\S+\s+/g` but this is only looking for spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an alternative in the regex for `<br>` tags.

```
/<br\s*\/?>|\S+?(\.|\s+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: `/(<br.*?>|[\w\.\,]+)/g`

Regex101 [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV7pU1/3).

Answer (score 0):

With the PHP regex engine (pcre) you can do that *(using `preg_match_all`)*:

```
~(?><br\b[^>]*>|\s+)*\K\w+[^<\w]*~
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/yB5xG2/1)

```
~           # pattern delimiter
(?>         # open an atomic group
    <br\b[^>]*> # a br tag
  |             # OR
    \s+         # one or more whitespaces
)*          # close the atomic group, repeat zero or more times
\K          # start the match result at this point
\w+       # word characters
[^<\w]*   # eventual non-word characters except an opening angle bracket
~
```